# UITableViewCell custom properties (in Swift)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift, realm

I'd like to be able to programatically attribute custom properties to a UITableViewCell (or any other object for that matter)

I'm using a delegate method in Swift w/ Realm.io DB (but I'm guessing it should be something similar in objective-c). Is using commented out line below == correct way of doing this?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell

    let object = array[UInt(indexPath!.row)] as Language
    cell.textLabel.text = object.title
    cell.position = object.position // does not produce any warnings
    return cell
}
```

Attributing title works just fine (because it is a label), but how do I attribute other (non-declared) properties to a cell so I can recover them later, when traversing the tableView?

```
for var row = 0; row < tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0); row++ {
    var cellPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
    var cell:Cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellPath) as Cell
    println(cell) // This prints out my cells, which contains a .text property, but no custom properties
}
```

Println produces the following result, but position property is not in it:

```
<_TtC8Verbum_24Cell: 0x7f9fb58bd3d0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Italiano'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9fb585bb70>>

<_TtC8Verbum_24Cell: 0x7f9fb58bb670; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 44; 320 44); text = 'Francais'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9fb58a44f0>>
```

UPDATE: I'm using a custom class for table cells:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    var position:Int?

    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to store data in the cell, rather than your `array` of data / other data source? If you really want to, you can certainly use a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` and declare your own properties.

Comment: Because I'm trying to implement table cells reordering and cannot thing of anything better than temporarily storing initial position values for each cell.. Anyway I am using a custom UITableViewCell on top of my controller (see my updated post). How do I implement this custom property in it and use it afterwards?

Comment: If you have a custom `Cell` class you can just add a [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) to it.

Comment: @jtbandes I've added ``var position:Int?`` into my custom Cell class, but attributing value directly doesn't do much...: ``cell.position = object.position``.

Comment: "Doesn't do much" means nothing... Please figure out a simple demonstration of the problem and update your post.

Comment: @jtbandes I'm sorry, you're right. I'm a noob in swift and I should have been more clear about this. I have updated my post with new code and debug message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` uses the [`CustomStringConvertible` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CustomStringConvertible_Protocol/index.html)'s `description` method to print out your object. Since you haven't provided a custom description, you're just seeing the regular UITableViewCell's description. You could simply `print(cell.position)` or:

```
var description: String { return "Cell with position \(position)" }
```